# How to sync time ubuntu desktop 13.10 client with Centos6.4 server using ntp

Tags: ntp

I have NTP server setup on my CentOS6.4 server and am trying to sync my Ubuntu 13.10 Desktop (AMD) client with it. I figured this would be easy having heard positive things about Ubuntu but it's not as easy as the instructions indicate. 
According to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime 
I should perform the steps below. The problem is there is NO "System menu on the top panel". Even the command line info is unclear. I use CentOS and Redhat daily but this is my first time using Ubuntu. Please help.

> Using the GUI This is how to enable NTP time synchronization using the
>   GUI (Graphical User Interface). Click on the System menu on the top
>   panel, go into the Administration sub-menu, and click on Date and
>   Time. Select the configuration option Keep synchronized with Internet
>   servers

Answer (score 1):

If you open a terminal, can you run this command:

```
sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
```

it should give you an output like this

```
21 Feb 08:56:06 ntpdate[4932]: adjust time server 91.189.89.199 offset -0.005915 sec
```

You can replace ntp.ubuntu.com with your own server address. 
This will verify that you can communicate via NTP. I run XFCE so my GUI menu is different. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer will do a one time sync with the server. If you want the machine to stay synced you need to edit /etc/ntp.conf

add a line like :

```
server your-centos.localdomain.com iburst
```

And then restart ntp:

```
/etc/init.d/ntp restart
```